# What caused diagonal cuts in the sidewalls of my tire?

Tags: tire

I noticed some strange damage on my rear tire, where there appear to be diagonally cuts going around the entire wheel.  I have no idea what might have caused this damage.  I first saw it a few months ago, but didn't think anything of it because I had just replaced my tires with these relatively fancy Panaracer kevlar tires so I figured they should hold up for at least a year.

Anyway, just a few days ago I felt my rear tire bumping and when I looked at it, I could see the tube is starting to bulge out slightly through the cracks in the tire sidewall.  The front tire is completely fine, but it's starting to look like I have to replace the back tire.

So my questions are, has anybody else dealt with this issue before?  Any ideas what might have caused this damage?  Am I indeed correct that the tire needs to be replaced?

The first picture has the most severe scarring, the second picture shows how it extends around the entire wheel.

[image: tire scarring]

[image: more damage]

Comment: Since replacing the tires, how many miles have you put on this bike, and on what sort of terrain? A year is not a ridiculous amount of time for a tire to wear out, depending on what you're doing with it.

Comment: Comparatively little and comparatively light.  I have probably ridden about 600ish miles, and all paved streets.

The thing that perplexes me the most is not whether the tire would wear out, but the unusual location and symmetry of the wear.  Having the tire rubber wear out would not surprise me, but I didn't expect to have whole-tire damage along the sidewall in such a regular pattern.  It seems to imply either a manufacturing defect or some very strange, regular abrasion.  I can think of nothing I had done that would cause such damage, so I'm just fishing for other ideas.

Comment: The periodic nature of the cuts *is* weird. I can't imagine any external cause for it. You're not putting too much pressure in the tube and overstressing the tyre, are you? Brakes or something on the bike (pannier mounts?) aren't rubbing on it?

Comment: My first thought was brakes also, but I checked and double checked.  They are definitely aligned with the metal rim, not the tire.  Pressure is generally moderate compared to maximum allowable (which for a hybrid tire like this is somewhere around 90 PSI IIRC).  I had a blowout a while back and I've been timid with overpressuring since then.

Comment: What size tire is this?  And tell us more about that blowout -- blowouts are very rare with modern tires and rims.

Comment: FTR, this tire is either a Panaracer Pasela, or Pasela TG. In it's narrowest form, a 700x23c they recommend a 100psi maximum. If this is as it appears, a 26 x 1.25 or 1.5, that pressure recommendation drops to 60 psi. Could possibly be a 700x38c which would be a max pressure of 90 psi.

Comment: The consistent and regular pattern on the sidewll is caused by the threads of the cloth base of the tire breaking. This happens when the rubber coating over the cloth becomes brittle due to age and dry rot. Your climate, or the age of the tire, possibly exacerbated by the pressure you're running in the tire, causes this kind of damage. It's no one's fault, but I'd recommend using black sidewalls, as natural rubber used in the tan sidewall doesn't last as well. It's common, and a well known issue in any bike shop.

Comment: I'll agree that I avoid gumwall tires because of the sidewall breakdown problem, though I generally don't see it for 3-5 years.  (On my old bike I ran Panaracer 27x1.25 tires that looked very similar to this -- the only suitable tires carried by the LBS.  IIRC, they were rated at about 90 PSI, and I'd guess I got about 4 years out of them before the tread wore out on the rear, at which time the front would be beginning to show a little checking, so it would get replaced too.)

Comment: Daral, inspect the front (& presumably undamaged) tire closely for any cracks in the rubber of the sidewall, or any sort of "orange peel" texture.  This would point at age as a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks to me like the tire's been run flat.  If not that then I'd say the tire's defective -- that the factory left out a layer of cord or some such.

What pressure have you been running (and how much do you weigh)?

Comment: I guess I should mention that I deflated the tire after I noticed the issue, so that it why it might appear to be running flat.  Under normal conditions I would keep it pretty well pumped up.

I would guess I pressurize it to somewhere around 75ish PSI, but I didn't use a gauged pump so I just got it up to the point of sufficient firmness.  My body weight is around 140 lbs (64 kg).

Comment: You're pretty light, and those tires usually aren't rated for more than 60-65 lbs, when new. You really don't need to run really high pressures for your body weight.

Comment: @Daniel, that damage is not from a run flat situation. That would look more like a single circular line around the whole circumference of the tire sidewall. In addition, it would look more "chewed" than cut, on that line.

Comment: Running at low pressure (though not completely flat) produces exactly that pattern of damage, from the sidewall buckling as it moves.  Plus there's apparent scuffing on the side of the tread (though it could be just dust pickup from laying the wheel down).

Comment: No, it doesn't. That can produce a wavy pattern, but it does not, ever, produce a pattern of diagonal slits in the tire that look to the inexperienced as if someone took a razor and cut zigzags in the sidewall. Which is what this picture shows.

Comment: Well, I guess we'll just agree to disagree.  The sidewall buckling will tend to occur again and again at the same spot on the sidewall, as the flexing makes that spot softer and softer.  This will eventually look like a "slit".

Comment: I guess so. Can you tell me why you are so certain you're right? Or is it that you're certain that I must be wrong? 15 years as a mechanic and a service manager, then an LBS manager say I know what I'm talking about. Still is what I do for a living, btw. "t-shirts older than me" doesn't provide much on your experience.

Comment: Well, when you see a tire like that you don't, as a bike shop guy, wonder why it happened, you just replace it -- that's your job.  I wonder why things happen -- that's my job.

Comment: Actually, as a bike shop manager, that is exactly my job. What exactly, do you do?

Comment: I annoy people in forums and chat rooms.

Comment: Just FYI anybody else runs across this, it turns out I had the tire accidentally underpressured (30-40 PSI).  I ended up replacing them, and hope to avoid the issue in the future by staying around 60 PSI.

Comment: I figured as much.

Comment: 30-40 PSI is still more than enough pressure for a rider of your weight. The pressure printed on the tire is a maximum pressure, not a minimum. But I'm glad you chose to unaccept my answer, and go with the answer with 0 votes.

Comment: At 30 PSI on that sort of tire the sidewall would have been "rippling": as it rolled.  Precisely what I was talking about.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you are right that the tire must be replaced.

No, the tires are not defective. This type of cross hatching is caused by age and weather deterioration. It appears like diagonal cuts because the weave of the cloth start breaking threads, and they are woven diagonally.

The tire is either at least 3-5 years old, or has been stored in a climate which speeds dry rotting. In this case the tire appears much older than that.

It is generally seen most obviously on tires which have tan side walls, as this one does. The tires with black side walls do the same thing, but it isn't as visible or as quick to happen.

A tire has a shelf life of 3-4 years, even if not ridden. I realize you said that you'd replaced them about a year ago. That could be climate affecting tire life, or it could be that they were old stock on the LBS shelf for some time before you bought them.  If you see crosshatching, or your tire feels papery and dry, rather than like rubber on the side wall, replace them. A blowout at speed is a dangerous thing, and a year of use is an acceptable lifetime.

FTR, this tire is either a [Panaracer Pasela](http://www.panaracer.com/urban.php#pasela), or Pasela TG. In it's narrowest form, a 700x23c they recommend a 100psi maximum. If this is as it appears, a 26 x 1.25 or 1.5, that pressure recommendation drops to 60 psi. Could possibly be a 700x38c which would be a max pressure of 90 psi.

Comment: If the tire were too old generally you'd see some checking of the sidewall rubber, which I can't discern in those photos.

Comment: The periodic cuts are what side wall checking becomes when left ...um.. unchecked. ;-)  Side wall checking is caused by the breaking of threads in the woven cloth that is the base of the tire. It weakens the cloth in that area, and allows a tear to begin. It looks like lines in the side wall when just beginning, but will eventually look like this. The extreme nature of the checking in this instance is what tells me the age is more than just a touch past the shelf life of the tire.

Comment: On old tires you will often see checking (due to the rubber getting hard) without any sign of the sidewall breakdown in the pictures.  It may be that the tires are too old, but my experience (I have a lot of experience with old stuff) wouldn't lead me to suspect that age is the primary problem.

Comment: Where is your experience from? You have strong opinions, which sometimes run completely contrary to accepted wisdom from every experienced mechanic and bike guru I've ever met. I've spent 15 years in bike shops, and I see these issues every day. I am not trying to say I know everything there is to know, but I know a lot, and I can recognize a damaged tire and its cause pretty easily on sight. What is your history, and your experience? If you can give me a reason for your certainty, maybe it will annoy me less when you say things I know are wrong.

Comment: I'm 62 years old, and have been riding bikes since I was five.  I've ridden at least 20K miles, maybe twice that over the years, some years doing 2000 miles, some years barely 200 (and a few years none at all), as my health and riding circumstances have had their ups and downs.  I don't ride fancy bikes, and stuff like tires I basically ride into the ground.  I've seen new tires and old tires and lots of situations in-between.

Comment: But I'll admit that now you've got me to thinking about the old Panaracers I had.  I can't remember if they were on my old Nishiki or on the Raleigh I had before that.  In any case it was a long time ago -- 20 years at least.  And, thinking back (though it didn't really occur to me at the time) the old Panaracers were crap -- the sidewalls did break down fairly rapidly, and I started mail ordering from Performance to get better quality. But I can still see in my mind's eye the sidewalls on those tires buckling as they rolled, when underinflated. The Panaracers were very sensitive to inflation.

Comment: Any gumwall tire is sensitive to underinflation. An tire will have problems with it. But the pattern of damage, while just as much a problem, doesn't look like this.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Yes, these are Panaracer Paselas, 700x35C.  I think I generally kept them slightly under pressure, but I didn't feel that it was so low as to cause this kind of damage.  And obviously the reason why I'm concerned over the root cause is that I want to change my behavior going forward to prevent this kind of damage, so it's definitely relevant to me.

Comment: The kind of damage caused by riding on depressurized tires, at your body weight, would mean you were running between 20-30 psi on a 90psi tire. The psi printed on the tire is a max pressure. Running 10-20% less is acceptable especially for a light guy like you.  Changing your behavior to prevent a problem is good. In this case, avoid gumwall tires, buy recent stock, and consider a new set every 2 years normal. I'll post some good tire options for you when I get back to the shop.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're right about replacing the tire--if you have any cracks in the sidewall and/or a bulging tube, a tire MUST be replaced. Judging by those pictures, I would replace the tire immediately.

Depending on the tire, and what you're doing with it, a year may or may not be an unreasonable length of time for a tire to wear out. Others with more experience will probably have something to say on that.

Comment: A year is not an unreasonable length of time to wear out the tread on a tire, but the tread on the tire looks to be only lightly worn.  A tire shouldn't experience sidewall failure like this in a year, unless it's abused somehow.

Comment: Or unless it sat on a LBS wall for a few years before purchase...

Answer (score 0):

I have had several rear tyres fail this way (most recently a Schwalbe racing ralph) 
Oddly the tyre "cuts" perfectly align with the spokes in a diagnonal away from each spoke. I ride a lot of canal paths so the crusty dry dust makes these patterns on the sidewall even when the tyre is brand new. I am wondering whether the spokes cause a vortex that carries dust triggering abrasion of the tyre wall until eventually it fails and you get bulges? I am going to try moving the tyre 1/4 of an inch around the rim every time a get a puncture to see if I can even out the abrasion. I always run the rear tyre at 50 or 60 PSI so "under inflation" cannot be the cause. I also run the front much lower and have never experience this on a front tyre

Comment: What is the width of the tire, and what do you weigh?  I'm guessing you're underinflated.